# S2D cluster not recognizing new phisical drive

Tags: storage-spaces, cluster-shared-volumes, storage-spaces-direct

I have a cluster of three ProLiant DL380p Gen8 servers with Windows Server 2019 OS. After Predictive failure warning on one of the physical drives, I retired it (Set-PhysicalDisk -Usage Retired) and removed id from pool (Remove-PhysicalDisk –PhysicalDisk $Disk). Than replaced it physicaly for a new drive. But the server still shows the old drive as possible for pooling and **not the new drive**. I can see it in the WAC or Get-PhysicalDisk cmdlet.

On the contrary - the HP iLO shows the new drive.

Any tips?

[Already detached and removed drive still showing.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QWsE8.png)

Answer (score 3):

That is common behavior on Storage Spaces Direct clusters running Windows Server 2016/2019 and is mostly caused by storage configuration cache update delays. After replacing the physical disk, you need to force the OS to update all storage-related information by running the following Powershell commands:

- [Update-HostStorageCache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/storage/update-hoststoragecache)
- [Update-StorageProviderCache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/storage/update-storageprovidercache)
- [Update-Disk](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/storage/update-disk)
- [Update-StoragePool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/storage/update-storagepool)

That should resolve your problem and show the actual data within all Windows management tools. As soon as you see the correct information, you may proceed with adding the [new disk to the pool](https://www.hyper-v.io/can-replace-failed-physical-disk-storage-spaces-direct-windows-server-2016/) as usual.